# Why am i getting an error while creating an sql temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, temp-tables

```
DECLARE @EndDate VARCHAR(10)
SET @EndDate='2018-01-19'

DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(10)
SET @Date='2018-01-19'

select * 
 into #temptable
 from(


 SELECT DISTINCT Device_Unique_ID__c as PhysicalDevice,
  CASE M.Model
  WHEN '426i (v2)' THEN 'V2'
 WHEN 'PXUV3D (v3 120v)' THEN 'V3'
 WHEN 'PXUV4D (v4 120v)' THEN 'X4'
 WHEN 'PXUV4E (v4 230v)' THEN 'X4'
 WHEN 'PXUV4F (v4 230v)' THEN 'X4'
 WHEN 'PXUV4K (v4 230v F Plug)' THEN 'X4'
 WHEN 'PXUV5D (v5 120v)' THEN 'X5'
 END AS Model#,

 DTransactionType,
 ActiveStatus,
 PDID as PhysicalDeviceID,
   --M.Name as AM1,contractEdate
    --Parent_Account_Owner__c,
   LogName as LogicalRobotName,
   LAccountName as LogicalAccountName,
    Type as LogicalAccountType,
   ALID as LogicalAccountID,
   Left(ALID,15) as LogicalAccountID15,
    CASE IIF(IIF(ImpAM is NULL,M.Name,ImpAM)='name','International',EVS)
    WHEN 'SODEXO' THEN 'Sodexo'
    WHEN 'x' THEN 'x'
   WHEN 'International' THEN 'International'
   Else 'Commercial' END as EVSProvider,
   ACID as ContractAccountID,
   ContractNumber,
   Convert(DATETIME,CAST(StartDate as DATETIME),105) ContractStartDate,
   Convert(DATETIME,CAST(EndDate as DATETIME),105) ContractEDate,
   Fee_per_Payment_Schedule__c as FeePerPaymentSchedule,
  Payment_Schedule__c as PaymentSchedule,
  Robots__c as Robots,
  Auto_Renew_or_Terminate__c as AutoRenew,
  ActivatedDate,
  CLIENT_SERVICES_DIRECTOR__C as RegionalAccountsDirector,
  ContractAccountName,
  ACType as ContractAccountType,
  Convert(DATETIME,CAST(D.Date as DATETIME),105)  LastFlashDate,
   D.Dys as DysSinceLastFlashed,
   DaysLastUpload,
  IIF((Dys>90 and (DaysLastUpload >90 or DaysLastUpload is null) and (Convert(DATETIME,CAST(EndDate 
 as 
 DATETIME),105)<Getdate())),'Dormant', 'NotDormant') as Dormancy,
 IIF(ImpAM is NULL,M.Name,ImpAM) as AM,
 CommissionedImplement as FirstCommissionAndImplementDtForLogicalDevice,
 recentstatus.Status__c,
 recentstatus.Decommissioned as DatePDeviceDecommissioned,
 recentstatus.LatestCommisDt as LastestCommissionDateForLogicalDevice



from
(Select distinct 
L.Device_Unique_ID__c,
PDID,
DTransactionType,
ActiveStatus,
Model,
LogID,
LogName,
LAccount,
LContract,
 LAccountName,
 AL.Name as LDAName,
 AL.Type,
 AL.Id as ALID,
 C.ContractNumber,
 C.StartDate,
C.EndDate,
C.Fee_per_Payment_Schedule__c,
C.Payment_Schedule__c,
C.Robots__c,
C.Auto_Renew_or_Terminate__c,
C.ActivatedDate,
AC.CLIENT_SERVICES_DIRECTOR__C,
AC.Name as ContractAccountName,
AC.Type as ACType,
AC.ID as ACID,
left(AC.ID, 15) as SalesForceCAccountID,
 U.Name,
 AC.PARENT_ACCOUNT_OWNER__c,
P.ACCOUNT_OWNER_TEXT__C,
 P.CASENUMBER


from 
(Select 
D.Device_Unique_ID__c,
D.ID as PDID,
D.Device_Transaction_Type__c as DTransactionType,
D.Active_Device__c as ActiveStatus,
D.Model2_c__c as Model,

D.Name as DName,

L.ID as LID,
L.Name as LName,
L.Account__C as LACCOUNT__C,
L.CONTRACT__C as LCONTRACT__C,
L.ACCOUNT_NAME__C as LACCOUNT_NAME__C,

 L2.ID as L2ID,
 L2.Name as L2Name,
 L2.Account__C as L2ACCOUNT__C,
 L2.CONTRACT__C as L2CONTRACT__C,
 L2.ACCOUNT_NAME__C as L2ACCOUNT_NAME__C,

 IIF(L.Id is null,L2.Id, L.Id) as LogID,
 IIF(L.Name is null ,L2.Name, L.Name) as LogName,
 IIF(L.Account__C is null,L2.ACCOUNT__C, L.Account__C) as LAccount,
 IIF(L.CONTRACT__C is null ,L2.CONTRACT__C,L.CONTRACT__C) as LContract,
 IIF(L.ACCOUNT_NAME__C is null ,L2.ACCOUNT_NAME__C,L.ACCOUNT_NAME__C) as LAccountName

 from ProdCopy.salesforce.Device as D
 left join [ProdCopy].dbo.Device as D1 on D.Name=D1.DeviceID
  left join [ProdCopy].[dbo].[LogicalDevice] as LD on LD.Id = D1.LogicalDeviceId
  Left join ProdCopy.salesforce.Logical_Device as L2 on LD.SalesforceId=L2.ID
  Left join ProdCopy.salesforce.Logical_Device as L on D.Logical_Device__c=L.ID) as L


  left join ProdCopy.salesforce.Account as AL on L.LAccount=AL.ID
  Left Join ProdCopy.salesforce.Contract as C on L.LContract=C.Id
  left join ProdCopy.salesforce.Account as AC on C.AccountId=AC.ID
  Left join [ProdCopy].[salesforce].[Case] as P on P.ACCOUNTID=AL.Id
  left join [ProdCopy].[salesforce].[User] as U on U.ID=AL.PARENT_ACCOUNT_OWNER__c
  )M
   Left join 
   (Select R.LatestCommisDt,R.Logical_Device__c,DAP.Device__c, 
   DAP.Decommissioned,CommisDt,DAP.Status__c from
                    (SELECT max(Convert(DATETIME,CAST((Commissoned_On__c) as DATETIME),105)) as 
   LatestCommisDt  ,Device__c,Logical_Device__c from [ProdCopy].[salesforce].[Device_Assignment]
                            Group by Logical_Device__c,Device__c) R left join

  (SELECT Convert(DATETIME,CAST((Commissoned_On__c) as DATETIME),105) as CommisDt  , 
   Convert(DATETIME,CAST((Decommissioned_On__c) as DATETIME),105)as 
   Decommissioned,Device__c,Status__c,Logical_Device__c
    from [XenexProdCopy].[salesforce].[Device_Assignment]
                )as DAP on DAP.CommisDt=R.LatestCommisDt and R.Device__c=DAP.Device__c and 
   R.Logical_Device__c=DAP.Logical_Device__c
                    group by 
   R.LatestCommisDt,R.Logical_Device__c,DAP.Device__c,DAP.Status__c,DAP.Decommissioned,CommisDt

                    ) RecentStatus on RecentStatus. [Logical_Device__c] =M.LogID and 
    Recentstatus.Device__c=PDID --Recent status of Physical Device
    left join


    (Select distinct 
    P.STATUS as ImpStatus,
    P.ACCOUNT_OWNER_TEXT__C as ImpAM,
    P.ACCOUNTID,
    P.ID

    from [ProdCopy].[salesforce].[Case] as P 
    where P.STATUS like 'IMP%'
    ) I on I.ACCOUNTID=M.ALID or I.ACCOUNTID=M.ACID


     left join (Select min(Convert(DATETIME,CAST((Commissoned_On__c) as DATETIME),105)) as 
     CommissionedImplement ,Logical_Device__c from [ProdCopy].[salesforce].[Device_Assignment]
                    group by logical_Device__c)as DA on DA.Logical_Device__c=M.LogID  --- 
   Implementation

    left join 



        (Select  right(C.[PhysicalDeviceId],6) as ID ,
          max((C.CycleStartTime_Date)) as Date,
          DATEDIFF(day, max((C.CycleStartTime_Date)),getdate()) as Dys
        from
        [ProdCopy].[report].[DisinfectionStats]as C
        group by C.[PhysicalDeviceID]
        union
        SELECT 
            right(a.[DeviceID],6) as ID,

            max(B.DateTimeStart) as Date,
            DATEDIFF(day, max(B.DateTimeStart),getdate()) as Dys

          FROM [ProdCopy].[v2legacy].[Device] as A left join [ProdCopy].[v2legacy]. 
   [DeviceLog]  as B on A.DeviceID=B.DeviceID
          group by a.[DeviceID]) D on M.Device_Unique_ID__c=D.ID
   left join
   (SELECT 
    DeviceLogSerialNumber
    ,min([DaysFromLastLogUpload])  as DaysLastUpload
    FROM [ProdCopy].[report].[LastUploadedLogCombined]  group by DeviceLogSerialNumber) LU on 
     LU.DeviceLogSerialNumber=M.Device_Unique_ID__c

    where 

  Type not in ('Former Customer', 'Former Sodexo Customer', 'Employee','Test Account')
  and
   ((LogName not like '%Training%'))
 and 
   (recentstatus.Status__c='Active')
 --and (recentstatus.Decommissioned is Null)---check for v2s only. once the V2s are gone, put the 
 clause back.
 and 
  (ContractAccountName is not null)

and (LAccountName  not like '%DMC%')
and (LAccountName  not like '%Intertek%')

 Group by
 Device_Unique_ID__c,
 M.Model,
 DTransactionType,
 ActiveStatus,
 PDID,
 LogName,
 LogID,
 LAccount,
 LContract,
 LAccountName,
 M.Name,
 EVS,
 Type,
  ALID,
   ACID,
 ContractNumber,
StartDate,
EndDate,
Fee_per_Payment_Schedule__c,
Payment_Schedule__c,
 Robots__c,
 Auto_Renew_or_Terminate__c,
 ActivatedDate,
 CLIENT_SERVICES_DIRECTOR__C,
 ContractAccountName,
 ACType,
 ImpAm,
 D.ID,
 D.Date,
 D.Dys,
 CommissionedImplement,
 RecentStatus.Status__c,
 Decommissioned,
 LatestCommisDt,
 DaysLastUpload


  Order by Device_Unique_ID__c desc)
```

Why am I getting an error message when trying to create a temp table for further analysis of the data..., I am trying to create a temp table from this query in order to join it to tables that are already existing.. ?

This error is preventing me from completing my task... it reads as follows The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

When I remove the order by function and but it after the last line of code it gives me an invalid syntax error... Any advice?

Comment: You have to create the table first, then you can insert into it.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: could you provide me with updated code?

Comment: Usually I would solve this by either removing the ORDER BY clause - or if I really needed that ORDER BY adding TOP 100 PERCENT to the select portion.

Comment: Just start over. That is an extremely complicated query made worse because of the formatting, extraneous commented-out code, nested derived tables, etc. And who knows if you have balanced your parentheses correctly. Every derived table will need an alias - so at a minimum you need to give one to the outermost derived table (which would follow the last closing parenthesis. I can't even find TOP in your query when i put it into notepad

Comment: The issue is caused by the `Order by Device_Unique_ID__c desc` right at the bottom - this was probably useful whilst the selection part of the query was being developed, but becomes a syntax error when re-written as an insert. As @SMor says, formatting makes it very hard to follow your example and see nesting

Comment: `create table #temptable (physicaldevice int, model# varchar(30))` then do your insert. I'm also making assumptions about your data types

Comment: does this go at the bottom of the code?

Comment: you'd need to create the temp table before you do the insert - and instead of `select * into #temp from ...` you'd use `insert into #temp select * from...`

Comment: You say when you remove the ORDER BY you get syntax error.  What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to follow your exact example, but this is how you would use the `TOP 100 PERCENT` approach.

```
SELECT 
    *
INTO
    #temp
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
        [object_id], [name]
    FROM 
        [sys].[tables]
    ORDER BY
        [name]
) A
```

But usually, the more correct thing is simply to remove the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT 
    *
INTO
    #temp
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        [object_id], [name]
    FROM 
        [sys].[tables]
) A
```

Comment: No - just no. The optimizer will see through this trick and ignore the top clause. And rows in a table have no inherent order so the order of rows in #temp is not "accessible" in later queries because rows in a table have no particular order by definition.

Comment: It's not a 'trick' - it's valid SQL, and it's precisely what the error message is suggesting "ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified" in the case of a sub-query that contains a necessary ORDER BY - Did you run the sample I provided?

Comment: But I am willing to learn, so if you think this will produce a sub-optimal query-plan, let me know

Comment: not exactly sure where in my code that should be placed?

Comment: Neither was I - but mainly because lack of indentation and aligning parentheses makes it very hard to see.

Comment: @StewartRitchie is right in that adding a `TOP 100 PERCENT` should resolve it, or simply removing it should work too, however the bigger issue is that @aped did not share what exactly the error message was when the `ORDER BY` was removed.